# using jquery index to add content to correct html element

Tags: jquery, html

I have a couple of divs with same class attribute. There is a  with

. I want to use the index of the clicked

to insert new dynamic content inside of correct div.

e.g. I have:

```
<div class="subPage">...</div>
<div class="subPage">...</div>
<div class="subPage">...</div>
```

I click the second tab and i want to add content to the second subpage. how do i achieve this?

Comment: so what have you tried so far?

Comment: You can use nth-child css selector.

Comment: Have a look at jQuery's [.index()](http://api.jquery.com/index/) and [.get()](http://api.jquery.com/get/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**LIVE DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/don/xayy4qmk/

---

**HTML:**

```
<div class="subPage">1</div>
<div class="subPage">2</div>
<div class="subPage">3</div>

<div class="clear"></div>

<div class="boxcontent">Box 1: </div>
<div class="boxcontent">Box 2: </div>
<div class="boxcontent">Box 3: </div>
```

**jQuery:**

```
$('body').on('click', '.subPage', function() {
    var clickedEq = $('.subPage').index(this);
    var numberEq = parseFloat(clickedEq)+1;
    $('.boxcontent').eq(clickedEq).append('You clicked, and here i am, the content to box ' + numberEq + '.');
});
```

**CSS:**

```
.subPage {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    background: #DDD;
    margin-right: 10px;
    float: left;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 50px;
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #808080;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.clear {
    clear: both;
}
.boxcontent {
    padding: 10px;
    background: #F5F5F5;
    margin-top: 20px;
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 13px;
}
```

Comment: Wondering what the css has to do with the question..!

Comment: Absolutely nothing. But the life is more beautiful with CSS. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`index()`](http://api.jquery.com/index/) method.

For example,

```
$(".tab").click(function(){ // where tab is the common class name of your tabs
  var index = $(this).index();
  $(".subPage").eq(index).append(); // you can access the corresponding subpage
});
```

Answer (score 0):

### Try this

```
   $('body').on('click', '.subPage', function () {
   $('.boxcontent').eq($(this).index()).append('You clicked, and here i am, the content to box '+($(this).index()+1)+ '.');
    });
```

Comment: I think you forgot to put the index number at the end there.

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
$('body').on('click', '.subPage', function() {
    $(this).html('You clicked, and here i am, the content to box.');
});
```

here is the example link
http://jsfiddle.net/patelmit69/37675jow/